# Characterization of $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ functions as Radon measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of standard  Euclidean space and let
$$\mathscr{M}(\Omega)=\{\text{Radon measures on }\Omega\}$$
I know that there is a standard embedding:
$$L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)\hookrightarrow \mathscr{M}(\Omega), \ \ \ f\mapsto \mu_f$$
So i can consider $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ as a subset of $\mathscr{M}(\Omega)$. I've not managed to prove the following proposition:

> Let $\mu\in \mathscr{M}(\Omega)$. Then $\mu\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ iff $\mu$ is absolutely continous with respect to Lebesgue measure.

It's trivial to prove that if $\mu\in \mathscr{M}(\Omega)$ then $\mu<<\mathcal{L}$ because the integral of a function over a $0$ measure subset is $0$. But I can't make any progress in the other direction.

Comment: I may be tired but I cannot see where you are stuck, if you know https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem

Comment: How are you defining Radon measure? Notice that for instance $x\mapsto x$ is locally integrable and indeed it defines a linear operator on $C_{00}(X)$: $f\mapsto \int xf(x)\,dx$, but $\mu(A)=\int_Ax\,dx$ is not a (signed) measure on the Borel sets (it takes both $\pm\infty$ values). Still, $\mu$ is a Radon measure (meaning a linear functional on $\mathbb{R}$ with certain uniform convergence property).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you so much for answering my questions even if they are stupid. I recently started my master degree in another university so I had to learn a lot of measure theory that I didn't study in my bachelor degree in a really brief period of time. :)